# Mean value theorem for integrals: how does the sign matter?

Tags: calculus, integration

The mean value theorem is that $\int_a^b f(x)g(x) dx = f(\xi) \int_a^b g(x) dx$ for some $\xi \in [a,b]$ if g(x) does not change sign on $[a,b]$. However, I can't see why the sign matters. There is a simple proof given on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_integration

and I'm sad to say that I can't see what step isn't valid if $g(x)$ changes sign. Can you point it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a counterexample, let $f(x)=g(x)=x$  on $[-1, 1]$.  Then $\int_{-1}^1 g(x)\, dx=0$, but $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)g(x) \, dx=1$, so we clearly can't choose $\xi$ so that $f(\xi)\int g = \int fg$.

In the Wikipedia proof, the problem comes in asserting the inequality
$$
\int_a^b mg(t)\,dt \le \int^b_af(t)g(t)\, dt
$$
where $m$ is a lower bound for $f$ (and its counterpart inequality for the upper bound). The justification for this inequality is pointwise inequality of the integrands, which only need hold if $g$ is everywhere non-negative; if $g(t)<0$ for some $t$, then in fact $mg(t) \geq f(t) g(t)$. (If $g$ is everywhere non-positive, the reverse inequalities all hold and the proof still goes through.)