# Is MVT for integral true without the condition, $g>0$ or $ g<0$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

The mean value theorem tells

" If $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous and $g$ is an integrable function that does not change sign on $[a, b]$, then there exists $c$ in $(a, b)$ such that

$\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx=f(c)\int_a^b g(x)dx$."

If $g$ changes its sign, is this theorem still true?

Answer (score 0):

No.

As pointed out in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946113/mean-value-theorem-for-integrals-how-does-the-sign-matter), just take $a=-1$, $b=1$, $f(x)=g(x)=x$.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Because when we prove this theorem we have to multiply both sides of the inequality $ m\leq f(x) \leq M$ by $g(x)$ and divide both sides of the inequality by $\int g(x)$ . So we have to know its sign.